# Getting error if I try to push multiple files in Git

Tags: git

If I do single file change then all ok. I can do git add, commit and finally push changes to origin.

But if I do change in multiple files then `git add` and `commit` is ok but when I do `git push origin master` I am getting below error...

```
D:\gitproject\ng2-SystemJS>git push https://github.com/intekhhab/ng2-SystemJS.git master
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com/': intekhhab@gmail.com
Password for 'https://intekhhab@gmail.com@github.com/':
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403 URLBlockeddueRestrictedCategory
Everything  up-to-date
```

Comment: Its not a login problem. Same happens for single file too. But for single file push gets succeed

Answer (score 0):

the error is telling you that the logon has failed, you could try going to your github repo logout and then login again and try to push from your console with the refreshed credentials